# How to increase the line spacing between the bibliography entry?

Tags: bibliographies

Hi everyone my document is written with 1.5. However, I would like to increase the line spacing between the bibliography entry. Here a portion of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{setspace}


(...)


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code

```
\begingroup
\setlength\bibitemsep{20pt} 
\setstretch{1}
\printbibliography
\endgroup
```

[image: A]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname37.bib}
    % examples form biblatex-examples.bib
    @article{sarfraz,
        author       = {M. Sarfraz and M. F. A. Razzak},
        title        = {Technical section: {An} algorithm for automatic capturing of
            the font outlines},
        year         = 2002,
        volume       = 26,
        number       = 5,
        pages        = {795-804},
        issn         = {0097-8493},
        journal      = {Computers and Graphics},
    }
    
    @article{bertram,
        author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
        title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on {Riemann} surfaces},
        journaltitle = {JAMS},
        date         = 1996,
        volume       = 9,
        number       = 2,
        pages        = {529-571},
        langid       = {english},
        langidopts   = {variant=american},
        shorttitle   = {Gromov invariants},
    }
    
    @book{kullback,
        author       = {Kullback, Solomon},
        title        = {Information Theory and Statistics},
        year         = 1959,
        publisher    = {John Wiley \& Sons},
        location     = {New York},
    }
    
    
    @online{markey,
        author       = {Markey, Nicolas},
        title        = {Tame the {BeaST}},
        date         = {2005-10-16},
        url          = {http://mirror.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf},
        subtitle     = {The {B} to {X} of {BibTeX}},
        version      = {1.3},
        urldate      = {2006-10-01},
        langid       = {english},
        langidopts   = {variant=american},
        sorttitle    = {Tame the Beast},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname37.bib}

\begin{document}

From \cite{sarfraz}.  See also \cite{bertram} and \cite{kullback} and \cite{markey}.

\begingroup
\setlength\bibitemsep{20pt} 
\setstretch{1}
\printbibliography
\endgroup

\end{document
```

Comment: Many thanks @Simon Dispa. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\bibitemsep` to set the line spacing between entries :

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{10pt}
\printbibliography
```

[image]

if you want to have 1-line spacing in each entry just add `\setstretch{1}`

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{10pt}
\printbibliography
```

[image]

Comment: Many thank @nlair.